# How to ignore a WB.Open pop out Userform?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to update a code of a macro-enabled excel file without changing anything on the sheets. The problem is upon opening the workbook, a userform automatically pops out which does something on a sheet upon filling up the form or just by closing it. The creator did not put some Admin button stuff to bypass the userform. How can I update a code inside the project and save it without altering the sheet contents or in other word, bypass the userform upon opening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the file while pressing "SHIFT" held down. This way macros are not executed.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know this "Shift thingy". hehe